# Add a POI in pgrouting

Tags: qgis, postgis, pgrouting, routing, osm2po

I am new of pgrouting.

I have created a new network using osm2po with both edges and nodes. 
Everything works fine, and I have tested the system using the Pgrouting Layer plugin for QGIS but I have noted that I am not able to use a table of POI that are not intersecting my network. [image: POI, edges and nodes]

I am not able to figure out how to add these POI as nodes, is there any easy way to solve this? I have already checked the workshop manuals and other discussions, but it seems to me that they don't explain how to do this operation, or, better, I understand that the POI should be on the edge in oder to split the lines before to create the table with the nodes, but if I have a table with hundreds of POI (e.g. all the bar/pubs in a city), and all these points are not in the edge, is there a way to fix it automatically?

Using QGIS 2.99 I see that there are some interesting tools for network analysis, if I try the shortest path algoritm using my table of POI I have this result[image]

I would like to reach the same result using Pgrouting.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [ST_Closespoint](http://www.postgis.org/docs/ST_ClosestPoint.html) function in PostGIS on your POIs before generating the network.

Here is a similar question: [How to connect points (bus stops), which don't lie on the lines (LINESTRING), to a network?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/95060/how-to-connect-points-bus-stops-which-dont-lie-on-the-lines-linestring-to)

Comment: Thanks Ylka,I have created a new "POI" table using ST_Closepoint and it works. Now, following your instructions, I should to split the lines with the new POIs and than I just simply to re-run the command for the topology. I'm going to try it immediatly. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

You could use one of the `withPoints` function to start routing from a POI.
The `withPoints` functions are not officially released yet, but they will be in the next release probably.

See this summary page about the concept with some network diagrams:
http://docs.pgrouting.org/2.4/en/withPoints-family.html#withpoints

The with points family of function give you the ability to route between arbitrary points located outside the original graph.